# How do I get these to align side by side horizontally using css?

Tags: css, layout

When i display below, the text 'Here is some text' is below the image - i want it to show to the right of the image?

```
<div style="width:50px;">
  <img src="http://assets.devx.com/MS_Azure/azuremcau.jpg" alt="blah" width="70" height="70" />
</div>

<div style="width:150px;">
  <h2>Here is some text</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:50px; display: inline-block;">
<img src="http://assets.devx.com/MS_Azure/azuremcau.jpg" alt="blah" width="70" height="70" />
</div>

<div style="width:150px; display: inline-block">
    <h2>Here is some text</h2>
</div>
```

changed float:left to display:inline-block. This is a better solution because it doesn't remove items from the document flow. Make sure you specify a width for every one though.

Comment: when i do that, the text appears underneath the image (using Google chrome)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
    <img src="http://assets.devx.com/MS_Azure/azuremcau.jpg" alt="blah" width="70" height="70" />
</div>
<div style="width: 300px;">
    <h2>Here is some text</h2>
</div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
```

This should work.